# NXT Display is messed up

Tags: nxt, repair, replacement-parts

I have an NXT 1.0 and the LCD display only displays noise.  Anyone know how to get one replaced or repaired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great video on YouTube that shows how to repair this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCZNc7tPop0

Basically, there are some surface mount capacitors on the PCB board for the screen/buttons that need a little bit of soldering to make sure they are properly electrically connected.

I have performed this repair myself with success.

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out